# RelativeLayout height to fill remaining space

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have the following layout in my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/logoLayout"  
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          -- some images
    </FrameLayout>


    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:gravity="center" 
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/logoLayout">

               Button 1
               Button 2
               Button 3
               Button 4

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                 Button 5
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout>
```

Maybe I didn't do it in the best way. What I want: have the Layout that contains the 4 buttons to use the entire space between the top and bottom layout, and I want to have the button equally arranged in the layout.

Something like this:http://img16.imageshack.us/i/androidq.png/

I add the whole layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">


    <!--The header of the page-->
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/logoLayout" 
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content">        

             <ImageView android:id="@+id/logoBackground" 
                        android:src="@drawable/logo_background_small"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

             <ImageView android:id="@+id/logoImage" 
                        android:src="@drawable/logo_small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="3dip"/>  

             <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                       android:text="@string/tracks"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:gravity="right"
                       android:textSize="22dip"
                       android:textColor="#ffffff"
                       android:padding="3dip">
             </TextView>              

        </FrameLayout>


        <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                         android:gravity="center" 
                         android:orientation="vertical"
                         android:layout_below="@+id/logoLayout"> 

                            <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                    android:layout_width="250dip" 
                                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_small_btn_look_around"
                                    android:background="@drawable/main_long_menu_button"
                                    android:text="@string/btn1" 
                                    android:textSize="18dip"
                                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                                    android:onClick="btnMyTracksOnClick">
                            </Button> 

                            <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                    android:layout_width="250dip" 
                                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_small_btn_look_around"
                                    android:background="@drawable/main_long_menu_button"
                                    android:text="@string/btn2" 
                                    android:textSize="18dip"
                                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/btn1">
                            </Button>

                            <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                    android:layout_width="250dip" 
                                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_small_btn_look_around"
                                    android:background="@drawable/main_long_menu_button"
                                    android:text="@string/btn3" 
                                    android:textSize="18dip"
                                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/btn2">
                            </Button>

                            <Button android:id="@+id/btn4"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                    android:layout_width="250dip" 
                                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_small_btn_look_around"
                                    android:background="@drawable/main_long_menu_button"
                                    android:text="@string/btn4" 
                                    android:textSize="18dip"
                                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/bt3">
                            </Button>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dip"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                        <Button android:layout_width="90dip" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="20dip"
                                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/sett_menu_button"
                                android:text="@string/back" 
                                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"/> 

         </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/logoLayout">

           Button 1
           Button 2
           Button 3
           Button 4

</RelativeLayout>
```

to:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/logoLayout">

           <!-- example button -->
           <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

the layout_weight should evenly space it out

Hope it works

Comment: I know this is late, but be careful when using weights. Weights tell each item to use the available space, including the inverse when there is not enough. This can result in views that look great on one device, but only show strips of each item on another.

Answer (score 55):

### Relative Layout Approach

I had a similar situation but I got it working using `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

I basically had 2 labels (textViews). The top one should fill the remaining space and the bottom label is a sentence of text that should wrap to its content but remain pinned to the bottom of the container. Both these views are inside a `RelativeLayout` container

So basically:

```
------- parent container top ------------
|
|
|
[label1 (auto expand)]
|
|
|
[label2 (fixed height)]
------- parent container bottom ------------
```

### Technique

1. For label 1, I set the layout params to `MATCH_PARENT` for both width and height so it auto expands.
2. Add a rule for label 1 so that it is `ABOVE` label 2 (this is the important part)

Then for label 2:

1. Use `MATCH_PARENT` for width and `WRAP_CONTENT` for height
2. Then add rule for label 2 to `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM`

This layout instruction is telling Android system:

Label 2 should wrap to its content and be pinned to the bottom of the parent container and at the same time, label 1 should be filling remaining space while sitting above label 2.

The important thing to remember is the view that is set to `ALIGN_PARENT_SOMETHING` e.g. `ALIGN_PARENT_TOP` or `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM` is the "priority view". All the other view that should fill remaining space should be set relative to this "priority view".

### Basic Example

Here's a demo using programmatic approach:

```
package com.zhang.relodemo;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // Member Variables
    // ---------------------------------------------------

    RelativeLayout container;

    TextView label1;
    TextView label2;

    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // Property Methods
    // ---------------------------------------------------

    public RelativeLayout getContainer() {
        return container;
    }

    public void setContainer(RelativeLayout container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public TextView getLabel1() {
        return label1;
    }

    public void setLabel1(TextView label1) {
        this.label1 = label1;
    }

    public TextView getLabel2() {
        return label2;
    }

    public void setLabel2(TextView label2) {
        this.label2 = label2;
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // Methods
    // ---------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initViews();
        initLayouts();
        addViews();
    }

    void initViews() {
        container = new RelativeLayout(this);

        label1 = new TextView(this);
        label1.setText("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");
        label1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        label1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        label1.setTextSize(20);

        label2 = new TextView(this);
        label2.setText("Label 2 is a short label compared to label1.It has two lines but take up a fraction of the space.");
        label2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        label2.setTextSize(20);
        label2.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    }

    void initLayouts() {
        container.setId(View.generateViewId());

        label1.setId(View.generateViewId());
        label2.setId(View.generateViewId());


        // ---------------------------------------------------
        // Parent Container Constraints
        // ---------------------------------------------------

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams containerLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        container.setLayoutParams(containerLayoutParams);



        // ---------------------------------------------------
        // Label Constraints
        // ---------------------------------------------------

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams label1LayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        // --------------------------------------
        // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT STEP HERE
        //
        // It tells label1 to be above label2
        // while expanding vertically.
        // --------------------------------------
        label1LayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, label2.getId());

        label1.setLayoutParams(label1LayoutParams);




        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams label2LayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        // ------------------------------------------
        // this pins label2 to the parent
        // container's bottom, preventing label1
        // from forcing label2 off bottom of screen
        // ------------------------------------------
        label2LayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        label2.setLayoutParams(label2LayoutParams);
    }

    void addViews() {
        getContainer().addView(getLabel1());
        getContainer().addView(getLabel2());

        this.setContentView(getContainer());
    }
}
```

Or its XML equivalent:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:text="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/label2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:text="Label 2 is a short label compared to label1.It has two lines but take up a fraction of the space."
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Should give you the following result:

[image: demo screenshot]

Comment: "Add a rule for label 1 so that it is ABOVE label 2 (this is the important part)" - I'm sure it is the important part, but without an example how will I ever know?

Comment: @user3690202 `android:layout_above` seems fairly self-explanatory.